# Docker trusted build doesn't show up in search

Tags: docker

I've created a trusted build by linking with my github account and the build process completed normally. However I can't find the image in the index page, nor with docker search.

The documentation [reads](https://index.docker.io/help/docs/#searching):

> You can search all publicly active repositories. If your repository isn't publicly active then it will not show up in the search results. To see what your repository status is, you can look at your profile page

When I go to this page I see that my repository status is "Initialized|Public|Owner", not "Active|Public|Owner". However I couldn't find how to make this "active".

How do I "fix" this?

(I have another image, which I pushed and which I can access normally, so I think that my account is configured correctly.)

Comment: It could be a temporary problem with docker.io. Others are complaining about it on IRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run into problems with the Index or any of our services, please file at ticket with support@docker.com or https://docker.zendesk.com and we can help you out. For help with Docker itself, Stack Overflow is a great option (as is IRC on Freenode's #docker).

-- Andy Rothfusz
Docker Support

Comment: Right. But that this was my first trusted build, so I assumed that the problem was on my side.